# PHP PDO Database

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to edit the whole info which is displaying through modal box in javascript but i am able to edit only first item in list not the other.Please tell me how can i edit/update the next item too. Below is my code

```
<?php 
session_start();
$sessionArr = $_SESSION['user_session'];

include_once '../connection.php';

$userDetails = [];
try{
$userId = $sessionArr['userId'];
// Set the PDO error mode to exception 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE iUserId=:USERID ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':USERID'=>$userId));
$userDetails =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() < 0)
{
echo "no data found";
exit;
}
} catch(PDOException $error){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $error->getMessage());
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body> 
<table>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th></th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($userDetails as $item): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php print $item['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $item['p_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $item['amount']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $item['date']; ?></td>
<td></td>
<td><button id="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<form action="" method="post">
<p id="emp">
<input type="text" name="e_name" id="e_name" placeholder="<?php echo 
$item['e_name']; ?>" required style='text-transform:uppercase'>
</p>
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal   
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I am trying to edit the whole info"* - This calls to `UPDATE` or `DELETE`; unsure what it is you want to do here and where the related code is for it.

Comment: It is not problem of update query it about that modal box is not opening for the second item i have looping problem.

Comment: have a look at your developer console then, see if there are errors

Comment: no it is not showing

Comment: You window.onclick function for closing the modal is a bit weird. And you have to add your button to that code, since your button probably is within the "window". You might also want to add "event.stopPropagation();" to stop DOM listening for that event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need a `key`/`id` so we can update or delete given record.

We will use for this a `id` stored in a table row, in `data-id` attribute, you can access this via `.dataset.id` in JS. (see my comments in code below, I explained it).

If you want to add an event listener you should never do something like this: (your code)

```
<td><button id="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
```

`id attribute` should always be unique, use `.class` instead.

I understand you want to update a values, so we append or `name` to `e_name` element `value` instead of `placeholder` like you did.

Here is working example. Please read all my comments so you have better understanding what is going on.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var closeButton = document.querySelector('.close');
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal


// Each edit button we add event 'click' listener 
for (var i = 0; i < editButtons.length; i++) {
    var editButton = editButtons[i];
    editButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    
      // Here we access our row tr, we have data-id with our id in it
      var row = this.closest("tr");

      // Here is your extracted data
      
      // Do whatever you need to
      var rowId = row.dataset.id;
      var rowDate = row.cells[0].innerText;
      var rowName = row.cells[1].innerText;
      var rowAmount = row.cells[2].innerText;
      var rowPhone = row.cells[3].innerText;
      
      // It's our data-action, we can simply switch from one action to another
      if (this.dataset.action === 'edit') {
        // edit stuff... 
        
        // We call to open a modal, simply by using css toggle
        modal.classList.add('visible');
        // We append all data from table row to our form  
        document.getElementById('e_name').value = rowName; 
        document.getElementById('e_amount').value = rowAmount;
        // ... even more stuff
        
      }
      
      if (this.dataset.action === 'delete') {
        // delete stuff
        
        // We want to remove record from db with given `rowId`
        // xhr/ajax request sends `rowId` to your backend 
        
        // you can a function here like removeElement(rowId);
      }
    });
}


closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// We call this function whenever we want, 
// eg. We click close button or after successful edit
function closeModal() {
  modal.classList.remove('visible');
}


function onFormSubmit() {
  //do your stuff
  console.log(this);
  
  // do xhr/ajax request
  

  // We prevent the form from reloading the page
  return false;
}
```

```css
#myModal {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

#myModal.visible {
  display: block;
}

#myModal .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th></th>
<th>Action 1</th>
<th>Action 2</th>
</tr>

<tr data-id="1">
<td>12-03-1990</td>
<td>Mark</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>1321132123</td>
<td></td>
<td><button data-action="edit" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
<td><button data-action="delete" class="myBtn">Delete</button></td>
</tr>


<tr data-id="1">
<td>01-12-1974</td>
<td>Tom</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>67567576</td>
<td></td>
<td><button data-action="edit" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
<td><button data-action="delete" class="myBtn">Delete</button></td>
</tr>


<tr data-id="3">
<td>15-06-1994</td>
<td>Jane</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>987897987</td>
<td></td>
<td><button data-action="edit" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
<td><button data-action="delete" class="myBtn">Delete</button></td>
</tr>



</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">CLOSE ME</span>
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return onFormSubmit();">
<p id="emp">
<input type="text" name="e_name" id="e_name" placeholder="name" value="" required style='text-transform:uppercase'>
<input type="text" name="e_amount" id="e_amount" placeholder="amount" value="" required style='text-transform:uppercase'>
</p>
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```